# How to Debug Nested Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, nested, ssms

What is the best practice to debug nested Store Procedures in Management Studio? 
(By nested I mean a Stored Procedure that executes other Stored Procedures before returning results)

How can someone set breakpoints at specific points inside nested Stored Procedures?

Comment: start at the most nested proc and work your way up...? You can use `RAISERROR()` at each level... there's a bunch of ways, starting with not nesting them so deeply.

Comment: I don't think this will work.. The most nested procedure accepts parameters and I don't know the value without running the "wrapper" procedure. Also architecture is fixed - not possible to change

Comment: what are most of the procs returning? or are they all returning single rows or are they full table datasets or? Point is, if it's a table then that's hard to do validation on to see if it would break in a join to another dataset. If it's a variable then obviously you can handle that logic